# chartjs autoSkip: true not working in Angular

Tags: chart.js

As title said, `autoSkip` not working for some reason. (Angular, chart.js 2.9.4)

```
 xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  },
  ticks: {
   autoSkip: true
  }
}],
```

How i can resolve that issue?

upd, how my code looks like:

```
this.chartOrders = new Chart('chartOrders', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(74, 164, 255, 0.2)'],
          borderColor: 'rgb(74, 164, 255)',
          pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
          pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
          pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(74, 164, 255)',
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(74, 164, 255)',
          pointBorderWidth: 8,
          pointHitRadius: 8,
          pointHoverRadius: 8
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      hover: {
        intersect: false
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      scales: {            
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
        },
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
            ticks: {
              precision: 0,
              beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: The `autoSkip` option is valid for all cartesian axes but not for other axes (see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration).

Comment: @uminder 
I added to ``scales: { ticks: { autoSkip: true } } ``- still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show more of your code, possibly a runnable code snippet.